# Android parsing json file

Tags: android, json, parsing

Json string contained in `String str`:

```
{conf:{"quantity_uom":"l",price_uom:"euro",distance_uom:"km",consumption_uom:"km/l"}}
```

Code:

```
try{
        if (str!=""){
            this.json = new JSONObject(str);
            this.quantityUom=this.json.getString("quantity_uom");
            this.distanceUom=this.json.getString("distance_uom");
            this.priceUom=this.json.getString("price_uom");
            this.consumptionUom=this.json.getString("consumption_uom");             
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
```

I have returned `No value for quantity_uom`. How I am doing wrong? String contain the json text.

Thank you so much.

Comment: `str!=""` will not work Java/Android. Use this: `!str.equals("")`

Comment: Your string is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try{
    if (!str.equals("")){
        Json obj = new JSONObject(str);
        this.json = obj.getJSONObject("conf");
        this.quantityUom=this.json.getString("quantity_uom");
        this.distanceUom=this.json.getString("distance_uom");
        this.priceUom=this.json.getString("price_uom");
        this.consumptionUom=this.json.getString("consumption_uom");             
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

You first have to get json object named 'conf' from string and from that json object get other values.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON string is not correct.

Try this:

```
{"conf":{"quantity_uom":"l","price_uom":"euro","distance_uom":"km","consumption_uom":"km/l"}}
```